# mysqldump entire structure but only data from selected tables in a single command

Tags: mysql

My database has 3 tables: table1, table2 and table3

I would like to do a mysqldump on this database with the following conditions:

- Dump structure for all tables
- Only dump data for table1 and table2, ignore data in table3

Currently, I do this with 2 mysqldump statements

```
mysqldump -u user -p -d db > db_structure.sql
mysqldump -u user -p db --ignore-table=db.table3 > table1_and_table2_data.sql
```

Import them in the same order they were dumped (structure, then data from table1 and table2)

Is there a way to combine this into a single mysqldump command?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't combine them in one command but you can execute both commands at the same time and output to the same file.

```
mysqldump -u user -p --no-data db > structure.sql; mysqldump -u user -p db table1 table2 >> structure.sql
```

to avoid having to enter the password twice you can do `-ppassword` (note the lack of space!). Also use `--no-data` in the first command or you end up with the data as well. -d isn't needed when you're doing just one database.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However I was wondering if nowadays is still imposible to do this in a more elegant way.

Comment: @EmilioNicolás Not that I'm aware of

Comment: `-d` is an alias for `--no-data` take a look at [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). It doesn't matter which one is used.

Answer (score 7):

Given you may want to pipe the output to another command, as I did, instead of just redirecting to a file and appending to that file in the next command, you could try (modified from the example of stask):

```
(mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 -d db && mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 db --ignore-table=db.table3) |\
your_command
```

... in my case:

```
(mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 -d db && mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 db --ignore-table=db.table3) |\
gzip -9 > filename.sql.gz
```

Enclosing the two mysqldump commands in parentheses creates a subshell whose output we pipe into gzip and then redirect that into a file.

PS: I've also been unable to combine it into one single mysqldump invocation, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in one command. But you definitely can merge the output to one file. Why not to wrap it in some shell script that does following:

```
mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 -d db > dump.sql && mysqldump -u $1 -p$2 db --ignore-table=db.table3 >> dump.sql
```

You will run this script with two parameters: username and password.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple, use --where clauses on the tables where you don't want data and give it an always false condition.  For instance, load data on foo and gah and only schema on bar:

```
mysqldump -u ... -p... myDatabase foo bar --where='1=2' gah > myfile.sql
```

So YES you can do this on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `INSERT INTO ...` part:

```
mysqldump \
  --opt \
  -u ${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASS} \
  ${DB_NAME} \
  | grep -v 'INSERT INTO `table3`' \
  | grep -v 'INSERT INTO `table4`'
```