# How to Exclude Data for Specific Tables

Tags: database, mysql, database-backups

I am using mysqldump to create a canonical installation script for a MySQL database. I would like to dump the data for able half of the tables in the database, but exclude the data from the other tables. I am aware of the following two commands:

--no-data

--ignore-table

But the first applies to all tables, and I believe the second excludes the table entirely from the dump (e.g. create statements) not just the data in the table. Anyone know how to use mysqldump to achieve my goal?

EDIT:

found a near duplicate question: [mysqldump entire structure but only data from selected tables in a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764387/mysqldump-entire-structure-but-only-data-from-selected-tables-in-a-single-command)

Comment: Note: you can't use --ignore-table with *multiple* databases. You might think because you specify the db and table in the switch, that you can use it on a multi-database dump, but you'll get "Couldn't find table"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about running two separate calls to `mysqldump`? One to create the database and ignore the tables you don't want data from. The other to just create the remaining tables without data. You could either run the two scripts separately, or concatenate them together to create a final script.

Comment: that's a nice idea, still going to keep my eye out for other solutions for now

Answer (score 2):

There is one other option to get everything done (in a single call to `mysql` itself) but it should probably never be attempted.

In tribute to H.P. Lovecraft, (and based upon [Anuya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125148/anuya)'s [stored procedure to create INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763722/stored-procedure-to-create-insert-statements-in-mysql)) here's *The Stored Procedure Which Must Not Be Called*:

**Note:** This unholy, arcane stored procedure would only be run by a madman and is presented below purely for educational purposes.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pseudoDump` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pseudoDump`(
  in_db varchar(20),
  in_tables varchar(200),
  in_data_tables varchar(200)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE Whrs varchar(500);
DECLARE Sels varchar(500);
DECLARE Inserts varchar(200);
DECLARE tablename varchar(20);
DECLARE ColName varchar(20);
SELECT `information_schema`.`TABLE_NAME` INTO tablename FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = in_db AND TABLE_NAME IN ( in_tables );
tabdumploop: LOOP
  SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
  LEAVE tabdumploop;
END LOOP tabdumploop;
SELECT `information_schema`.`TABLE_NAME` INTO tablename FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = in_db ;
datdumploop: LOOP
  SELECT group_concat(concat('concat(\'"\',','ifnull(',column_name,','''')',',\'"\')')) INTO @Sels from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;
  SELECT group_concat('`',column_name,'`') INTO @Whrs from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;
  SET @Inserts=concat("select concat('insert IGNORE into ", in_db,".",tablename," values(',concat_ws(',',",@Sels,"),');') as MyColumn from ", in_db,".",tablename, " where 1 group by ",@Whrs, ";");
  PREPARE Inserts FROM @Inserts;
  EXECUTE Inserts;
  LEAVE datdumploop;
END LOOP datdumploop;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

... thankfully, I was saved from witnessing the soul-wrenching horror this procedure must surely wreak by [MySQL Bug #44009](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44009) ...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u user -h host.example.com -p database table1 table2 table3
```

Comment: your example is not clear, are table1-3 suppose to have their data included or excluded here (i'm assuming the former)?  also, just to double check, will i still get create table statements etc. for all the other tables not in that list?

Comment: @Stephen, look at the switches that are available for mysqldump

Comment: I have but there are many of them and I couldn't find what I am looking for. But from I can see in the documentation, your example will exclude all tables except for table1-3 entirely, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: The list of tables does not exclude but include them, and it removes them from the dump completely, not just their data leaving the structure to be dumped. This answer is basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you need here:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysqldump-selectively-dump-data/

Using where statements is probably the easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the where statement applies to all tables being dumped.

Comment: I think this may actually come in handy for another thing I need to do, which is limit the data exported for certain tables.  As @Don pointed out, this applies to all tables being dumped, but I can chain mysqldump calls together targeting one table at a time for the desired result.